# how to get clicked row data Jquery data table

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have jquery `datatable` and its grouped according to date. I want to add new event action when click group header. But I cannot get clicked group data. How to get clicked group data. I used below code, still cannot get `clicked` group data.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var otable;
        otable = $('#data').DataTable({
            "bProcessing":true,
            "bServerside":true,
            "sServerMethod":"post",
            "sAjaxSource": "http://localhost/test/test",
            "bDestroy":true,
            "aaSorting":[[2,'desc']]
        }).rowGrouping({
            bExpandableGrouping:true,
            iGroupingColumnInex:6
        });



    $('#data body').bind('click','tr.group',function(){
       var data = $('#data').DataTable().row(this).data()
    });
 })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass the `tr` element to an instance of the DataTables api. I changed your `bind` to `on` because it's the recommended way, change it back if you're using an older version.

```
$('#data body').on('click','tr.group',function(){
    var data = $(your table selector).DataTable().row(this).data();
});
```

EDIT: cleaner solution by commenter, thx

Comment: No need to pass jQuery object, `row(this)` will also work.

Comment: Post your html and js please. Have you initialize DataTables correctly?

Comment: How did you implement my answer, did you use `otable` or `$('#data')`?

Comment: It creates this error $('#data').DataTable().row is not a function

Comment: I can't see anything that would cause that error. If you make me a jsfiddle recreating the error then i can help more.